# Consume WCF service in Titanium

Tags: wcf, titanium

I have written a code to consume the WCF service in my Titanium Project.

```
Alloy.Globals.wcfservice=function callservice()
{

        //fetching data from server.
        var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
        xhr.setTimeout(1200);
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(xhr.statusText);

        xhr.onerror = function(e)       /* on  error in getting data from server */
        {
            //check response status and act aaccordingly.
            if (xhr.status != 200) {
                alert("The service is currently unavailable. Please Try Again Later.");
                return;
            }
        };

        //on getting response from server.
        xhr.onload = function()
        {
            alert(this.responseText);

            var response = XML.parse(this.responseText);
        };

        //set the url for the service to the get student courses
        var request_url = getWebserviceURL() + "GetAvailableAppointmentFromWCF";
        console.log(request_url);
        xhr.open("POST", request_url);
        xhr.send();
};
```

But I always receive status as 0, "the service is currently unavailable. Please Try Again Later" . What wrong am I doing in this code?

Comment: if you try to load the wcf service from your browser it works?

Comment: WCF services will not work on browser. But I have tested it using the SOAP UI and it works

Comment: why wouldn't it work in the browser? note that you are trying to consume it using createHTTPClient so my thought is that if it doesn't work in the browser why would it work with http client?

Comment: Could you please provide me with the method of how to test it on browser? Sorry for the beginner type of question

Comment: I have checked this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728279%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and I totally agree that it must run on web browser. However do you think that I have to make changes on the server side WCF code? to make it run on browser?

Comment: I'm guessing so. If it was me I would give it a try since what you are actually issuing from Titanium is an http call. If you are using TCP binding in your WCF you can use TCP connection from within titanium to try and connect to it as well.

Comment: I guess you can use the postmaster extension for chrome to test it? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en

Comment: I have discussed it with my server side colleague and he said that he will change the code to REST WCF service, to achieve the above functionality. However my question to you is do with any other network call other than http in Titanium to attain WCF service?